# Remote access to OS X Lion from OS X Leopard and Windows

Tags: windows, osx-lion, remote-desktop, osx-leopard

I need to access to a Mac running OS X Lion remotely from a Mac running OS X Leopard and Windows.

Is there any software to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to enable remote management and screen sharing in Mac OS X Lion (It enables some sort of VNC Server).

From my Mac Leopard: *Finder > Go to > Connect To Server*. Type:

```
vnc://macosx-lion-ip-adress
```

It will prompt you to type the remote Mac OS X login/password and then launch a screen sharing application. From Windows you can use a VNC client.

Answer (score 0):

Set up VNC on mac and this  will solve your problem. VNC stands for virtual network  computing and provide acess to remote computer. Here is a detailed guide.

http://www.wikihow.com/Setup-VNC-on-Mac-OS-X

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. Try to add the essential information to your answer, so it's still useful once the linked web page is changed or deleted.

Comment: The link contains a complete step by step instruction. I thought it not right to copy down someone else' work.That is why i provided only link.